# How to make scrolling smoother (not anchor links, just scrolling in general)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on a website about myself, because I want to become a freelancer some day and make websites for clients. I thought something like smooth scrolling would make the site look much cooler. I have looked at multiple jQuery plugins online, but they do not seem to give me the smooth animation I want.

DEMONSTRATION OF SMOOTH SCROLL I WANT -> http://bayshoresolutions.com

Please do not rate negatively unless you have left a comment telling me why so I can fix my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find one by searching section scroll. Just to let you know this is considered bad UX design by many. Check out here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81721/is-using-pages-section-scrolling-good-for-ux

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/